Kernel of map between Lie algebra representations
Consider the $\mathfrak{sl}_7(\mathbb{C})$ representation $\Gamma_{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} \otimes \Gamma_{0,0,1,0,0,0,0} \subset \wedge^2 \wedge^3 (V \oplus V^*)$, where $V$ is the standard representation and $V^*$ is its dual. This decomposes as
$$\Gamma_{1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} \otimes \Gamma_{0,0,1,0,0,0,0} \cong \Gamma_{0,0,0,1,0,0,0} \oplus \Gamma_{1,0,1,0,0,0,0}.$$
I'm trying to understand how vectors here lie in each of $\Gamma_{0,0,0,1,0,0,0}$ and $\Gamma_{1,0,1,0,0,0,0}$ but something is off in my reasoning.
Given the vector $(e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3) \wedge (e_4 \wedge e_5 \wedge e_5^*)$, I can project onto $\wedge^6 (V \oplus V^*)$ and then contract to $e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4 \in \wedge^4 V \cong \Gamma_{0,0,0,1,0,0,0}$.
I would then expect the kernel of this projection map to be exactly $\Gamma_{1,0,1,0,0,0,0}$ (since the target space $\wedge^5 V \otimes V^*$ doesn't contain a copy of $\Gamma_{1,0,1,0,0,0,0}$).
Now consider the vector $(e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3) \wedge (e_3 \wedge e_3^* \wedge e_4)$. This is in the kernel of the map described above. But I also could include it in $\wedge^3 (V \oplus V^*) \otimes \wedge^3 (V \oplus V^*)$ and then apply the map $\text{id} \otimes C_3$ (where $C_3$ is the contraction map on $\wedge^3 (V \oplus V^*)$) to get $(e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3) \otimes e_4$, which projects to $e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4$. How is this possible?

Found my error. $(e_4 \wedge e_5 \wedge e_5^*)$ doesn't lie strictly in $\Phi_{1,0,0,0,0,0,0}$
